# How to convert json to Unknown type Struct

Tags: json, go

```
var a interface{}
a = xxStruct{}
json.Unmarshal(jsonData,&a)
```

The "a" become to be a map, not a struct. For java, I could do it like this:

```
Object obj = new XXObject();
String json = JSON.toJSONString(obj);
obj = JSON.parse(json,obj.getClass())
//and also I can convert obj to original object.
//but How do this in "go"?
XXObject x = (XXObject)obj;
x.xxxSet(); //call method as normal.
```

I try using reflect.ValueOf(), reflect.TypeOf() and type convert like
v:=a.(XXStruct) etc. 
but it doesn't work, What should I do?

Comment: What doesn't work? What are you trying to do? Include your code. What problem are you encountering?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `a` as a variable of type xxStruct, not interface{}:

```
var a xxStruct
```

Comment: Like SpringMVC Interceptor, I want to convert json in iris's Interceptor and send object to next handler, not convert json in every controller.

Comment: Don't try to write Java/Spring in Go, it won't work. You could write a helper that takes an `interface{}` but you'd still need to pass that helper an instance of a concrete type to unmarshal into.